# Chosen JQuery not loading in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@sherzelsmith/add-a-filtering-multiple-tag-system-with-autocomplete-to-your-rails-model-in-rails-5-1bf88cd53e9) on how to add tags to posts, problem is in the post form ,the chosen jquery plugin doesn't take effect. It should look like this: [image]

but here's what I'm getting instead, no autocomplete and i can't select multiple tags:[image]

My application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require chosen
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree
//= require semantic-ui
//= require social-share-button
```

application.css.scss

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require chosen
 *= require social-share-button
 */
```

gemfile

```
   source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
      gem 'rails-assets-tether', '>= 1.3.3'
      # add the line below
      gem 'rails-assets-chosen'
```

Chosen script at the bottom of my application.html.erb

```
<script>
  $(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
    $('#post_tag_ids').chosen({
      allow_single_deselect: true,
      width: '100%'
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: @jvillian yes i am

Comment: You might need to use `$(document).on 'turbolinks:load'` as discussed in [the guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#page-change-events).

Comment: that fixed it, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the guide on [Working with JavaScript in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) and in particular section [5.2 Page Change Events](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#page-change-events).

You'll likely need to use:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load'
```

Because, as the guide says,

> Turbolinks overrides the normal page loading process

Personally, I remove Turbolinks from all of my projects. But, I'm odd that way.